# How to use gsl in cython

Tags: python, c, cython, gsl

I am trying to write a cython function that can be called from a python script which uses c gsl library to calculate the spearman correlation and the respective p value using a t distribution. My unsuccessful .pyx file is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np

def spearmanr(cdef double v1, cdef double v2, cdef int N):

     cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h":
         double gsl_stats_spearman(double data1[],size_t stride1,double data2[],size_t stride2, size_t n)

     cdef int strides = 1
     cdef int n = N

     cdef double r = gsl_stats_spearmanr(v1,strides,v2,strides,n)

     cdef double tstat=r*((n-2)/(1-r**2))**0.5  

     cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_ranhist.h":
         double gsl_cdf_tdist_Q(double x, double nu)

     cdef double nu = N  %% Do I need to Type Cast?
     cdef double pval=gsl_cdf_tdist_Q(stat,nu)

     return r,pal
```

when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
running build_ext
cythoning spear_coxen.pyx to spear_coxen.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def spermanr(cdef double v1, cdef double  v2, cdef int N):
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

spear_coxen.pyx:4:13: Expected an identifier, found 'cdef'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def spermanr(cdef double v1, cdef double  v2, cdef int N):
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

spear_coxen.pyx:4:25: Expected ')', found 'v1'
building 'spear_r' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall   -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/Anaconda2-2.5.0/envs/python27/include/python2.7 -c spear_coxen.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/spear_coxen.o
spear_coxen.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result    of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am really not sure if any of this is correct syntax as I could not find as searches have not yielded anything but trivial examples. If anybody could offer assistance it should be much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put `cdef` in your function arguments.  I.e.

```
def spearmanr(cdef double v1, cdef double v2, cdef int N):
```

Should just be:

```
cpdef spearmanr(double v1, double v2, int N):
```

And move your GSL declarations above that function declaration, not inside of it.  Then it can access the functions you've declared, e.g.

```
cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h":

    double gsl_stats_spearman(double data1[],size_t stride1,double data2[],size_t stride2, size_t n)
```

Do the same with the other `extern`.

Also your declarations look incorrect (I'm not looking at the GSL docs) but `double data1[]` if you mean this to be an array it should be `double[:,:] data1` or a vector `double[:] data1` for a NumPy memoryview.  Let me know if it doesn't compile after doing that for `data1` and `data2` variables declared as such...